# How to force Excel to interpet xs:double value 123.45 as 123.45, not 12345 using Danish Regional settings

Tags: xml, excel, xsd

### TL;DR

I have an XML file with a schema and `<value>123.45</value>`. The schema says this is a double.

Still Excel decides to interpret that as 12345 if the Regional format setting is "Danish (Denmark)" when importing the XML file. (Works fine with "English (United States)"). Excel decides that in Danish, the decimal separator (*also for XML files*) is comma, not period.

Is there some way I can e.g. modify the XML to force Excel to do the right thing and interpret 123.45 as 123.45 regardless of Regional settings? I'd like to avoid two XML flavors depending on users' Windows settings. :-(

Or does anyone have a better forum to ask? Googling for excel and decimal separator gives many, many newbie posts about how to *show* numbers with ',' or '.', not how to control import, so I'm trying here.

### Details

#### (I think) '.' is the only valid way to represent decimal separator for XML doubles

I'll claim that numbers in XML may only use '.' as decimal separator, and so Excel under "Danish (Denmark)" is *wrong*. Comma (',') as a decimal separator is never valid. Our schema sets the value field as a "double", which is defined in https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#double that says:

> The representations for exponent and mantissa must follow the lexical rules for integer and decimal.

https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#decimal says:

> decimal has a lexical representation consisting of a finite-length sequence of decimal digits (#x30-#x39) separated by a period as a decimal indicator.

But alas, Excel doesn't seem to care about that... :-( Or have I misunderstood something?

#### How I import data into Excel

I have a [data.xml](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/pmorch/8fa7c15ef120dfb345f8fc25e8f415d8/raw/1231835337826f6d1f6508ba8f861f2a2f4cfe9a/data.xml) which links to a [schema.xsd](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/pmorch/8fa7c15ef120dfb345f8fc25e8f415d8/raw/1231835337826f6d1f6508ba8f861f2a2f4cfe9a/schema.xsd) in a [github gist](https://gist.github.com/pmorch/8fa7c15ef120dfb345f8fc25e8f415d8).

The essense is that the `schema.xsd` has:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">
...snip...
<xs:element name="value" type="xs:double"/>
```

When I import this in Excel 2016 like this:

- Go to Data ribbon
- New Query
- From Other Sources
- From Web
- enter [url](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/pmorch/8fa7c15ef120dfb345f8fc25e8f415d8/raw/1231835337826f6d1f6508ba8f861f2a2f4cfe9a/data.xml)
- (The first time I did this in Excel with the gist URL, I had to choose the most specific host here, you may not)
- Select "record"

Now, if Regional settings have format "English (United States)" you'll see a value of 123.45. If you have format "Danish (Denmark)", you'll see a value of 12345. :-(

#### Changing Regional Settings

You can change the Regional Settings like this:

- Settings
- Time & Language
- (scroll down)
- Additional date, time & regional settings
- Change date, time, or number formats
- (You now see the) "Regional" settings dialog.

[image: RegionalSettings]

Here you can change the "Format:" setting.

On that Regional dialog, there are also "additional settings", and there it doesn't matter what we set "Decimal Symbol" and "Digit grouping symbol" to "Numbers" and the similar settings under Currency also have no effect. It also doesn't matter what we set "Decimal separator" and "Thousands separator" to in Excel's Options / Advanced.